# How to generate a point that outside the polygon

Tags: python

I want to randomly generate a point that outside the polygon.

For example, I have three polygons in my space, and I would like to get a point that doesn't overlap into any polygon. It means the point is collision-free and randomly generating.

Does anyone now how to get it?

I only can get the method to check a point whether inside the polygon.

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You could imagine generating outside the bounding box, or the incircle. You could imagine random points and checking whether point lie inside or outside the polygon...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the shapely library to check if a point is in or outside of a polygon, and generate random positions until one is outside of them.

Examples are found in the documentation:

[Shapely documentation](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/project.html#usage)

Polygons are easily defined by passing the coordinates in the constructor and you can check if a polygon contains a point using:

```
>>>from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
>>>print(Polygon([[0, 0], [0, 4], [4, 4], [4, 0]]).contains(Point(1.0,1.0)))
True
```

You can experiment with it until getting your desired result.